# What is the sans serif font used by the Neurological Foundation of NZ logo?

Tags: font-identification

I noticed the logo for the [Neurological Foundation of New Zealand](https://neurological.org.nz/) and was wondering what the font was.

I've run the logo through the usual font identification tools and came up empty.

Can someone please identify the sans font in this logo.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is FF Scala Sans Pro (seems to be the bold and regular)

- [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts/ff-scala-sans)

[image]

---

The trick for running it through a font identifier is breaking it up into parts which the software can easily identify (usually 1 word will suffice)

I started with the word **NEUROLOGICAL** and if I came up with an unsure match, I would run the other words, but the first result I got was a perfect match.

I matched it to the other characters  which seemed to have unique characteristics (**A C G W**)